# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am currently doing the basic macOS React Native tutorial where you install react native's cli and run the `AwesomeProject` with it to be familiarized with how it all works and got everything to work setup-wise. However, when I attempt to build and run the `AwesomeProject` I get a super long error with the following message at the end of the terminal:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-bobdwvxurhjqxdcgnmikbsefmjkb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00018F30.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

When I try to build and run on Xcode I get this error message in the build log:
`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I have tried doing the following:

1.) Clean Build Folder -> Build on Xcode

2.) Delete Podfile.lock, Pods folder, and AwesomeProject.xcworkspace file and then running `pod install`.

3.) Making sure all dependencies were updated by doing `pod update`.

4.) Making sure node, yarn, npm, and gems were all downloaded and installed at their latest versions. I am using Ruby version 2.7.6.

None of them have helped. Any help will always be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this error by commenting the below code block:

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" ]]; then
    # shellcheck source=/dev/null
    . "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -s "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" ]];      
then
    # shellcheck source=/dev/null
    . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"   
fi
```

This code block is located in `node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh`

Then do the following:

1. rm -rf build Pods Podfile.lock
2. run pod install.